# Next and Fluence, unexpected token { in node_modules/

Tags: webpack, babeljs, next.js, fluence

I'm trying to make [Fluence Network](https://fluence.network) and Next.js work together. I get this error, that's probably due to a webpack / babel configuration issue:

```
/Users/XXX/code/current/XXX/node_modules/fluence/dist/fluence.js:24

import { TendermintClient } from "./TendermintClient";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.fluence (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:660:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at Module../services/fluence.js (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:506:65)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at Module../services/koos.js (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:548:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at Module../reducers/actions.js (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:464:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:23:31)
    at Module../pages/index.js (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:377:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jt/Documents/code/current/koos/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js:23:31)
```

So apparently, Next is complaining because Fluence is using ES6 imports. I'm looking for a solution but if anybody had a pointer I wouldn't say no.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [latest Fluence version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluence/v/latest) (0.3.4 as of now), it has been updated to be compatible with nextjs.

Your `next.config.js` should look something like this:

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules');

module.exports = withTM({
    transpileModules: ['fluence']
});
```

`next-transpile-modules` can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules)